# Use different nginx server for different .local domains

Tags: networking, dns, nginx, domain, avahi

I am trying to run different servers on different `.local` domains on my RPi.
This is my nginx default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name raspberrypi.local;
}
```

`/etc/hosts` file -

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

Now using `avahi-publish` I aliased another domain

```
avahi-publish -a -R foo.local 192.168.68.120
```

But when I access this domain, it also shows the nginx default html, which I do not want. I understand that I have not configured any other server running on that domain yet, but I expect it to give unable to connect or unreachable.

If that is not possible, is there a way to have multiple `.local` domain names, which are not aliases ?

Comment: You should add virtual host in nginx config with new domain

Comment: Yeah that seemed to work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I access this domain, it also shows the nginx default html, which I do not want. I understand that I have not configured any other server running on that domain yet, but I expect it to give unable to connect or unreachable.

You will not get "unable to connect" because you configured Nginx to listen on *all* addresses for this server – that's what `listen *:80` means here; if it's listening on `0.0.0.0` aka `*` then it'll accept connections made to any local IPv4 address. (The `[::]` does the same for IPv6.)

(The `server_name` option does not influence this – all it does is select the correct server{} block based on the HTTP 'Host' header in the received request, *after* the connection has been established. In other words, it implements name-based virtual hosts, rather than IP-based.)

If you want the virtual hosts to be IP-based, change your server{} blocks to listen on specific IP addresses instead of the wildcard address:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.68.xxx:80;
}
```

Keep in mind that this will fail if Nginx starts before the address has been assigned to an interface. (This could be avoided using [IP_FREEBIND](https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2014-March/005134.html) but it seems Nginx doesn't support that yet.)

Comment: I think I will go with multiple virtual host for now, assigning multiple IP and virtual interfaces seems like a hassle. Thank you.